# lambda sink connector doesn't picks the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY values in my ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to push my kafka topic data to an aws lambda function with nordstrom lambda sink connector, after setting up the aws credentials as an environmental variable still the connector shows the below error

Exported the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY values as

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXX 
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

my connector.json config:

```
  {
    "name": "example-lambda-connector",
    "config": {
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "connector.class": "com.nordstrom.kafka.connect.lambda.LambdaSinkConnector",
      "topics": "example-stream",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "aws.region": "ap-south-1",
      "aws.lambda.function.arn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:111111111:function:example-function",
      "aws.lambda.invocation.timeout.ms": "60000",
      "aws.lambda.invocation.mode": "SYNC",
      "aws.lambda.batch.enabled": "false"
      }
     }
```

getting the below error:

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@503af16e: profile file cannot be null, WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@76a59f2c: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following config:

```
{ ...
"aws.credentials.provider.class": "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain",
...}
```

See AWS docs for explanation of DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html

> AWS credentials provider chain that looks for credentials in this
> order:
>
> - Environment Variables
> - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY    (RECOMMENDED since they are recognized by all the AWS SDKs and CLI except for .NET), or AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY (only recognized by Java SDK)
> - Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
> - Web Identity Token credentials from the environment or container
> - Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
> - Credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 container service if AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" environment variable is set and security manager has permission to access the variable,
> - Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service